# Kernel can't find rootfs on STM32MP151

Tags: linux, kernel, stm32

I'm trying to get a board based on [this](https://www.myirtech.com/list.asp?id=658) module up and running using recent boot stages and kernel (6.1.*).
Can't use the manufacturer provided files, because those are atleast two years old and incomptatible.
This mainly comes down to writing the device tree and using these with Yocto following the [ST guide](https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/How_to_create_your_own_machine). So far I've experienced a lot of [issues](https://github.com/michieltjampens/tios/blob/main/core/code/troubleshooting.md) which were mostly caused by migration or bad docs.

The current issue i'm trying to resolve, is that while trying to start the kernel it can't find the rootfs.

```
Starting systemd-udevd version 253.1^
root '/dev/disk/by-partuuid/491f6117-415d-4f53-88c9-6e0de54deac6' doesn't exist or does not contain a /dev.
```

First thing I checked is that the uuid of that partition is indeed correct.

According to `mmc part` used in u-boot (snippet):

```
 8     0x0002d000      0x00747bff      "rootfs"
        attrs:  0x0000000000000000
        type:   0fc63daf-8483-4772-8e79-3d69d8477de4
                (linux)
        guid:   491f6117-415d-4f53-88c9-6e0de54deac6
```

Which matches, so that's not it. With `ums mmc 1` I confirmed that the rootfs indeed contains a folder named dev.

Other option was something wrong with the sdmmc node in the devicetree. But that's copy paste of the u-boot one and it found the bootfs that contains the kernel.

Next up was [something wrong with the regulators](https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mpus-products/root-dev-mmcblk0p6-doesn-t-exist-or-does-not-contain-a-dev/td-p/65350) in the device tree. Missing or incorrect 'compatible' setup. Changed it based on [this](https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/Regulator_overview) and the [pmic dtbindings](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/linux/blob/v6.1-stm32mp/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/mfd/st,stpmic1.yaml) but didn't make a difference either.

That was pretty much the only relevant thing I could find. Any ideas on what might cause this? The device tree in question can be found [here](https://github.com/michieltjampens/tios/tree/main/core/code/dts/kernel).

Other things I've tried so far:

- Build the kernel and rootfs without yocto, to have more control over it. Didn't help.
- Build optee with debug level on 4, didn't provide new info.
- Replaced 'partuid' (the word) with uuid in extlinux.conf, didn't make a difference.
- Tried to figure out what happens between u-boot loading and it loading the kernel (so what does bootcmd actually do), everything works as expected.
- Went through the docs again to see if i missed something, found one thing. That fixed something else, but not the rootfs issue.
- The fs didn't seem to be resized to the partition size (no idea why), so tried manually doing that. Didn't resole it either.

Comment: Cause was not having interrupt settings in the pmic node...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those three lines weren't inside the pmic: stpmic@33 node and caused all the issues...

```
interrupts-extended = <&exti 55 IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_FALLING>;
interrupt-controller;
#interrupt-cells = <2>;
```

Comment: I also fixed the issue *"Starting systemd-udevd version 253.1^
root '/dev/disk/by-partuuid/491f6117-415d-4f53-88c9-6e0de54deac6' doesn't exist or does not contain a /dev"*  as described above